# Android ListView Zoom

Tags: android

How to enable zoom for listView for my app?I have found solution here: https://github.com/matrixxun/PullToZoomInListView but I get error: Unexpected cast to  PullToZoomListView: layout tag was listView!

listView = (PullToZoomListView)findViewById(R.id.usb_list);

USBProductID.class

```
public class USBProductID extends AppCompatActivity
{
    PullToZoomListView listView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.usbproductid);

        //ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.usb_list);
        listView = (PullToZoomListView)findViewById(R.id.usb_list);
        ViewGroup headerView = (ViewGroup)getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.header,listView,false);
        listView.addHeaderView(headerView);
        String[] items = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.list_items);
        ListAdapter adapter = new ListAdapter(this,R.layout.rowlayout,R.id.textcompany,items);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
}
```

ListAdapter.class

```
public class ListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String>
{
    int vg;
    String[] item_list;
    Context context;

    public ListAdapter(Context context, int vg, int id, String[] item_list)
    {
        super(context, vg, id, item_list);
        this.context = context;
        this.item_list = item_list;
        this.vg = vg;
    }

    // Hold views of the ListView to improve its scrolling performance
    static class ViewHolder
    {
        public TextView txtmanufacturer;
        public TextView txtvendorid;
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
    {
        View rowView = convertView;
        if(rowView == null)
        {
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            rowView = inflater.inflate(vg,parent,false);
            ViewHolder holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.txtmanufacturer = (TextView)rowView.findViewById(R.id.textcompany);
            holder.txtvendorid = (TextView)rowView.findViewById(R.id.textvendorid);
            rowView.setTag(holder);
        }

        String[] items = item_list[position].split("_");
        ViewHolder holder = (ViewHolder)rowView.getTag();
        holder.txtmanufacturer.setText(items[0]);
        holder.txtvendorid.setText(items[1]);
        return  rowView;
    }
}
```

PullToZoomListView.class

```
public class PullToZoomListView extends ListView implements
        AbsListView.OnScrollListener {
    private static final int INVALID_VALUE = -1;
    private static final String TAG = "PullToZoomListView";
    private static final Interpolator sInterpolator = new Interpolator() {
        public float getInterpolation(float paramAnonymousFloat) {
            float f = paramAnonymousFloat - 1.0F;
            return 1.0F + f * (f * (f * (f * f)));
        }
    };
    int mActivePointerId = -1;
    private FrameLayout mHeaderContainer;
    private int mHeaderHeight;
    private ImageView mHeaderImage;
    float mLastMotionY = -1.0F;
    float mLastScale = -1.0F;
    float mMaxScale = -1.0F;
    private OnScrollListener mOnScrollListener;
    private ScalingRunnalable mScalingRunnalable;
    private int mScreenHeight;
    private ImageView mShadow;

    public PullToZoomListView(Context paramContext) {
        super(paramContext);
        init(paramContext);
    }

    public PullToZoomListView(Context paramContext,
            AttributeSet paramAttributeSet) {
        super(paramContext, paramAttributeSet);
        init(paramContext);
    }

    public PullToZoomListView(Context paramContext,
            AttributeSet paramAttributeSet, int paramInt) {
        super(paramContext, paramAttributeSet, paramInt);
        init(paramContext);
    }

    private void endScraling() {
        if (this.mHeaderContainer.getBottom() >= this.mHeaderHeight)
            Log.d("mmm", "endScraling");
        this.mScalingRunnalable.startAnimation(200L);
    }

    private void init(Context paramContext) {
        DisplayMetrics localDisplayMetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
        ((Activity) paramContext).getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay()
                .getMetrics(localDisplayMetrics);
        this.mScreenHeight = localDisplayMetrics.heightPixels;
        this.mHeaderContainer = new FrameLayout(paramContext);
        this.mHeaderImage = new ImageView(paramContext);
        int i = localDisplayMetrics.widthPixels;
        setHeaderViewSize(i, (int) (9.0F * (i / 16.0F)));
        this.mShadow = new ImageView(paramContext);
        FrameLayout.LayoutParams localLayoutParams = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(
                -1, -2);
        localLayoutParams.gravity = 80;
        this.mShadow.setLayoutParams(localLayoutParams);
        this.mHeaderContainer.addView(this.mHeaderImage);
        this.mHeaderContainer.addView(this.mShadow);
        addHeaderView(this.mHeaderContainer);
        this.mScalingRunnalable = new ScalingRunnalable();
        super.setOnScrollListener(this);
    }

    private void onSecondaryPointerUp(MotionEvent paramMotionEvent) {
        int i = (paramMotionEvent.getAction()) >> 8;
        if (paramMotionEvent.getPointerId(i) == this.mActivePointerId)
            if (i != 0) {
                int j = 1;
                this.mLastMotionY = paramMotionEvent.getY(0);
                this.mActivePointerId = paramMotionEvent.getPointerId(0);
                return;
            }
    }

    private void reset() {
        this.mActivePointerId = -1;
        this.mLastMotionY = -1.0F;
        this.mMaxScale = -1.0F;
        this.mLastScale = -1.0F;
    }

    public ImageView getHeaderView() {
        return this.mHeaderImage;
    }

    public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent paramMotionEvent) {
        return super.onInterceptTouchEvent(paramMotionEvent);
    }

    protected void onLayout(boolean paramBoolean, int paramInt1, int paramInt2,
            int paramInt3, int paramInt4) {
        super.onLayout(paramBoolean, paramInt1, paramInt2, paramInt3, paramInt4);
        if (this.mHeaderHeight == 0)
            this.mHeaderHeight = this.mHeaderContainer.getHeight();
    }

    @Override
    public void onScroll(AbsListView paramAbsListView, int paramInt1,
            int paramInt2, int paramInt3) {
        Log.d("mmm", "onScroll");
        float f = this.mHeaderHeight - this.mHeaderContainer.getBottom();
        Log.d("mmm", "f|" + f);
        if ((f > 0.0F) && (f < this.mHeaderHeight)) {
            Log.d("mmm", "1");
            int i = (int) (0.65D * f);
            this.mHeaderImage.scrollTo(0, -i);
        } else if (this.mHeaderImage.getScrollY() != 0) {
            Log.d("mmm", "2");
            this.mHeaderImage.scrollTo(0, 0);
        }
        if (this.mOnScrollListener != null) {
            this.mOnScrollListener.onScroll(paramAbsListView, paramInt1,
                    paramInt2, paramInt3);
        }
    }

    public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView paramAbsListView, int paramInt) {
        if (this.mOnScrollListener != null)
            this.mOnScrollListener.onScrollStateChanged(paramAbsListView,
                    paramInt);
    }

    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent paramMotionEvent) {
        Log.d("mmm", "" + (0xFF & paramMotionEvent.getAction()));
        switch (0xFF & paramMotionEvent.getAction()) {
        case 4:
        case 0:
            if (!this.mScalingRunnalable.mIsFinished) {
                this.mScalingRunnalable.abortAnimation();
            }
            this.mLastMotionY = paramMotionEvent.getY();
            this.mActivePointerId = paramMotionEvent.getPointerId(0);
            this.mMaxScale = (this.mScreenHeight / this.mHeaderHeight);
            this.mLastScale = (this.mHeaderContainer.getBottom() / this.mHeaderHeight);
            break;
        case 2:
            Log.d("mmm", "mActivePointerId" + mActivePointerId);
            int j = paramMotionEvent.findPointerIndex(this.mActivePointerId);
            if (j == -1) {
                Log.e("PullToZoomListView", "Invalid pointerId="
                        + this.mActivePointerId + " in onTouchEvent");
            } else {
                if (this.mLastMotionY == -1.0F)
                    this.mLastMotionY = paramMotionEvent.getY(j);
                if (this.mHeaderContainer.getBottom() >= this.mHeaderHeight) {
                    ViewGroup.LayoutParams localLayoutParams = this.mHeaderContainer
                            .getLayoutParams();
                    float f = ((paramMotionEvent.getY(j) - this.mLastMotionY + this.mHeaderContainer
                            .getBottom()) / this.mHeaderHeight - this.mLastScale)
                            / 2.0F + this.mLastScale;
                    if ((this.mLastScale <= 1.0D) && (f < this.mLastScale)) {
                        localLayoutParams.height = this.mHeaderHeight;
                        this.mHeaderContainer
                                .setLayoutParams(localLayoutParams);
                        return super.onTouchEvent(paramMotionEvent);
                    }
                    this.mLastScale = Math.min(Math.max(f, 1.0F),
                            this.mMaxScale);
                    localLayoutParams.height = ((int) (this.mHeaderHeight * this.mLastScale));
                    if (localLayoutParams.height < this.mScreenHeight)
                        this.mHeaderContainer
                                .setLayoutParams(localLayoutParams);
                    this.mLastMotionY = paramMotionEvent.getY(j);
                    return true;
                }
                this.mLastMotionY = paramMotionEvent.getY(j);
            }
            break;
        case 1:
            reset();
            endScraling();
            break;
        case 3:
            int i = paramMotionEvent.getActionIndex();
            this.mLastMotionY = paramMotionEvent.getY(i);
            this.mActivePointerId = paramMotionEvent.getPointerId(i);
            break;
        case 5:
            onSecondaryPointerUp(paramMotionEvent);
            this.mLastMotionY = paramMotionEvent.getY(paramMotionEvent
                    .findPointerIndex(this.mActivePointerId));
            break;
        case 6:
        }
        return super.onTouchEvent(paramMotionEvent);
    }

    public void setHeaderViewSize(int paramInt1, int paramInt2) {
        Object localObject = this.mHeaderContainer.getLayoutParams();
        if (localObject == null)
            localObject = new LayoutParams(paramInt1, paramInt2);
        ((ViewGroup.LayoutParams) localObject).width = paramInt1;
        ((ViewGroup.LayoutParams) localObject).height = paramInt2;
        this.mHeaderContainer
                .setLayoutParams((ViewGroup.LayoutParams) localObject);
        this.mHeaderHeight = paramInt2;
    }

    public void setOnScrollListener(
            OnScrollListener paramOnScrollListener) {
        this.mOnScrollListener = paramOnScrollListener;
    }

    public void setShadow(int paramInt) {
        this.mShadow.setBackgroundResource(paramInt);
    }

    class ScalingRunnalable implements Runnable {
        long mDuration;
        boolean mIsFinished = true;
        float mScale;
        long mStartTime;

        ScalingRunnalable() {
        }

        public void abortAnimation() {
            this.mIsFinished = true;
        }

        public boolean isFinished() {
            return this.mIsFinished;
        }

        public void run() {
            float f2;
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams localLayoutParams;
            if ((!this.mIsFinished) && (this.mScale > 1.0D)) {
                float f1 = ((float) SystemClock.currentThreadTimeMillis() - (float) this.mStartTime)
                        / (float) this.mDuration;
                f2 = this.mScale - (this.mScale - 1.0F)
                        * PullToZoomListView.sInterpolator.getInterpolation(f1);
                localLayoutParams = PullToZoomListView.this.mHeaderContainer
                        .getLayoutParams();
                if (f2 > 1.0F) {
                    Log.d("mmm", "f2>1.0");
                    localLayoutParams.height = PullToZoomListView.this.mHeaderHeight;
                    ;
                    localLayoutParams.height = ((int) (f2 * PullToZoomListView.this.mHeaderHeight));
                    PullToZoomListView.this.mHeaderContainer
                            .setLayoutParams(localLayoutParams);
                    PullToZoomListView.this.post(this);
                    return;
                }
                this.mIsFinished = true;
            }
        }

        public void startAnimation(long paramLong) {
            this.mStartTime = SystemClock.currentThreadTimeMillis();
            this.mDuration = paramLong;
            this.mScale = ((float) (PullToZoomListView.this.mHeaderContainer
                    .getBottom()) / PullToZoomListView.this.mHeaderHeight);
            this.mIsFinished = false;
            PullToZoomListView.this.post(this);
        }
    }
}
```

usbproductid.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:orientation="vertical"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ListView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:id="@+id/usb_list"/>

    <TextView
        android:text="USB Vendor IDs"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_marginTop="18dp"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: show me your xml file,

Answer (score 0):

Use this :

```
<PullToZoomListView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:id="@+id/usb_list"/>
```

in you activity

```
    mZoomView.setAdapter(adapter);

    mZoomView.getHeaderView().setImageResource(R.drawable.dsf);
    mZoomView.getHeaderView().setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
```

Comment: When I changed to this list now shows but I cannot zoom it <com.example.pavle.usbotgenabler.PullToZoomListView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:id="@+id/usb_list"/>

Comment: yes , i forget to mention `PullToZoomListView` with package name

Comment: use listView instead of mZoomView in your case

Comment: yes you can zoom only header image while swipe down

Comment: How to zoom list ?

Comment: yes i understand what to you want, but this code works only for zoom header image

Comment: github , you will find there

Comment: Can any of this two be used : https://github.com/wangzl8128/SclaeListView https://github.com/imalhasaranga/ZoomListView